# Mocha test factorization and backtrace

Tags: javascript, exception, mocha.js

I run many Mocha tests that look like this :

```
it('should fail blabla', function () {
    return <functionThatReturnsAPromise>()
        .then(function () {
            assert(false);
        }, function (err) {
            assert.strictEqual(err.message, 'Foobar is undefined');
            assert.strictEqual(err.code, 'EUNDEFINEDFOOBAR');
        });
});
```

The only things that vary among my tests are the **function**, the **code** and the **message**.

I wanted to factorize the code like this:

```
function shouldBeRejected(promise, code, message) {
    return promise
        .then(function () {
            assert(false);
        }, function (err) {
            assert.strictEqual(err.code, code);
            assert.strictEqual(err.message, message);
        });
}
(...)
it('should fail blabla', function () {
    return shouldBeRejected(<functionThatReturnsAPromise>(),
                            'EUNDEFINEDFOOBAR', 'Foobar is undefined');
});
```

It works but when some tests failed, all my backtraces reference the `shouldBeRejected` function and so, I'm losing all information about the real test that failed.
Is there a way to get a more "intelligent" backtrace pointing to the shouldBeRejected calls that indirectly raise the error? Maybe with a captureStackTrace somewhere?